Objects become invisible in material preview mode
All objects are visible in solid mode. When I switch to preview, absolutely all objects become invisible, but at the same time I can see them if I switch to camera mode. I tried switching EEVEE and CYCLES. I have an AMD video card, but when I open another file and transfer the model there, all display modes work correctly, so I think the problem is not in the drivers.




hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

I've never used it myself so don't know its function, but you have Render Region checked on the View tab of the N panel. Uncheck it to show your objects.


Omg, thanks. There are a lot of settings in blender

Yes indeed! That one is detailed under this section in the Blender Manual below the Passepartout entry.
